# Creating a big pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My code is retrieving historical data of 365 days back from today of 50 different stocks.

I want to store all those data in one dataframe to make it easier to analyse, here I want to filter all those data, date wise and calculate number of advancing/declining stocks at a given date.

My code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import nsepy as ns

#setting default dates
end_date = date.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(365)

#Deriving the names of 50 stocks in Nifty 50 Index
nifty_50 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIFTY_50')

nifty50_symbols = nifty_50[1][1]




for x in nifty50_symbols:
    data = ns.get_history(symbol = x, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    big_df = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\My\Getting data from NSE\advances.py", line 27, in <module>
    big_df = pd.concat(data)
  File "C:\Users\Abinash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 212, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\Abinash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 227, in __init__
    '"{name}"'.format(name=type(objs).__name__))
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

I am very new to python, I went through the tutorial of pandas and saw that pandas.concat was used to merge multiple dataframes into one. I might have understood that wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I will try it next time.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because the error message indicated you directly what you'd done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data for concatenation has to be iterable for example list.

```
results = []
for x in nifty50_symbols:
    data = ns.get_history(symbol = x, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    results.append(data)

big_df = pd.concat(results)
```

Comment: Thank you, the above codes fixed my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem very recently, that's why I am showing off now :) Good luck!